# jQuery Sum array

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

I want to get the total and a average from a number of rides.
Now i'm Stuck with this now the whole day, first i tried it with span's around it but i thought maybe with a array is better, hope somebody can help me with the missing piece.

Example: http://jsbin.com/inapey/31/edit

```
<tbody id="rides">
    <tr>
        <td class="muted"><small>Mr.</small></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      <!-- Every ride of this person -->
        <td class="ride_km" style="display:none;">225,75</td>
      <!-- Sum & Average of this person -->
        <td class="ride_total_km"></td>
        <td class="ride_average_km"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="muted"><small>Mrs.</small></td>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
     <!-- Every ride of this person -->
      <td class="ride_km" style="display:none;">150,300</td>
      <!-- Sum & Average of this person -->
        <td class="ride_total_km"></td>
        <td class="ride_average_km"></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var total = 0;

  $('#rides tr').each(function() {
  var RidesKM = $(this).fin('.ride_km').html().split(",");  
  var arr = jQuery.makeArray(RidesKM); 
  alert(arr);

  var SumKM = ???;
  var AveKM = ???;  

  /* Total KM's */
    $(this).find('.ride_total_km').html(SumKM);
  /* Average KM's */
    $(this).find('.ride_average_km').html(AveKM.toFixed(0));  

  }); 
});
```

Comment: Woh, I just realized something, the ',' is a delimiter for every value. I thought it was the decimal seperator (in French we use a comma not a period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated answer.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9pr3A/6/)

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rides tr').each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        var sum = 0;

        that.find('.ride_km').each(function () {
            var values = $(this).text().split(',');
            $.each(values,function() {
                sum += parseFloat(this);
             });
            /* Total KM's */
            that.find('.ride_total_km').html(sum.toFixed(2));
            /* Average KM's */
            that.find('.ride_average_km').html((sum / values.length).toFixed(2))
        });
    });
});
```

It's weird though that you store the values in a hidden td. I would suggest (if you could do all the calculations in javascript or if possible from the server (if you're using something like PHP or other).

Comment: Thank you very much, i use expression engine (which is PHP) and i found some add ons for math but that doesn't work with the output i have so i have to be creative with the hidden span...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the total for each person. In this case, you don't need the `total` variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rides tr').each(function() {
    var SumKM = 0;
    var RidesKM = $(this).find('.ride_km').html().split(",");

    for (i = 0; i < RidesKM.length; i++) {
      SumKM += parseInt(RidesKM[i]);
    }

    var AveKM = SumKM / RidesKM.length;  

    /* Total KM's */
    $(this).find('.ride_total_km').html(SumKM);
    /* Average KM's */
    $(this).find('.ride_average_km').html(AveKM.toFixed(0));  
  }); 
});
```